# sending file with pony by sinatra app - missing file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

I want to send a email from my sinatra application.

Here is the code:

```
    require 'pony'
    class Cms < Application

      get "/mail" do
        Pony.mail :to => 'to@gmail.com',
          :from => "from@gmail.com",
          :subject => "Thanks for signing my guestbook!",
          :via => :sendmail,
          :via_options => {
              :address     => 'smtp.gmail.com',
              :port     => '587',
              :user_name     => 'user@gmail.com',
              :pass     => 'pass',
              :enable_starttls_auto => false
          },
          :body => erb(:"cms/mail")
        redirect '/'
      end

    end`
```

Thin is starting application with no errors, but When i request myapp.local/mail i've got an error:

```
    LoadError - no such file to load -- mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp:
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/configuration.rb:31:in lookup_delivery_method'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/configuration.rb:25:in delivery_method'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:111:in delivery_method'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:116:in initialize'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:50:in new'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:50:in new'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pony-1.4/lib/pony.rb:174:in build_mail'
        /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/pony-1.4/lib/pony.rb:138:in mail'
        ./app/controllers/cms.rb:8:in GET /mail'
```

File `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this same error when I was using the inline configuration of the Mail gem:

```
mail.delivery_method :sendmail
mail.deliver!
```

Removing that first line, and moving the configuration to immediately following the loading of the mail gem fixed it.

Wherever in your app you `require 'mail'` just configure it immediately:

```
require 'mail'
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :sendmail
end
```

Update: This worked for awhile... But then for some reason I began seeing this error:

`` rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `parse': no such file to load -- mail/elements/address_list (LoadError) ``

Update2: The failures happen randomly it seems.  Something about the way the autoload works in Ruby 1.8.7-p374 is causing it to not be able to find files that do in fact exist.  Also, I am using slimgems not rubygems.

These are the hacks I've had to implement so far to use Mail with multi-part email and sendmail delivery method:

```
require 'mail'
require 'mail/network/delivery_methods/sendmail'
require 'mail/elements/address_list'
require 'mail/fields/common/common_address'
require 'mail/elements/content_type_element'
require 'mail/elements/address'
require 'mail/elements/content_transfer_encoding_element'

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :sendmail
end
```